# Geolocation alert won't stay on screen

Tags: html, geolocation, alert

I am trying to implement basic geolocation on my web app but the alert in Chrome won't stay on screen; it pops up at the bottom but then disappears before I can click any of the options.

[geolocation alert won't stay on screen](http://thp.philpenny.co.uk/find-a-clinic-in-the-uk.html)

Comment: The dodgy alert can be seen on Chrome on mobile, on desktop it doesn't seem to appear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an error handler function. Try adding:

```
  var success = function(position) {
    //do something with position
  };
  var failure = function(error) {
    console.log('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
    // error.code can be:
    //   0: unknown error
    //   1: permission denied
    //   2: position unavailable (error response from location provider)
    //   3: timed out
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);
```

Also, consider adding `{timout: 5000}` (or any other length of time) as a 3rd parameter, since the function's [default timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/timeout) to search for location is Infinity. See the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

Comment: Thanks, adding your suggestion worked, thanks for the links as well, I'll read through them.